# Iterating a NodeList consisting some tags with same name using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, tags, loops

I'm trying to read in an XML using DOM in Java

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
<user>
    <name>Leo</name>
    <email>****@****.com</email>
        <food-list>
            <food>Hamburgers</food>
            <food>Fish</food>
        </food-list>
</user>
</record>
```

My current solution is

```
    for (int userNumber = 0; userNumber < masterList.getLength(); userNumber++) {

           Node singleUserEntry = masterList.item(userNumber);
           if (singleUserEntry.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

              org.w3c.dom.Element userEntryElement = (org.w3c.dom.Element) singleUserEntry;



              System.out.println("name : " + getTagValue("name", userEntryElement));
              System.out.println("email : " +getTagValue("email", userEntryElement));
              NodeList foodList = userEntryElement.getElementsByTagName("food-list").item(0).getChildNodes();
              for(int i = 0; i < foodList.getLength(); i++){
                  Node foodNode = foodList.item(i);
                  System.out.println("food : " + foodNode.getNodeValue());
              }

private static String getTagValue(String sTag, org.w3c.dom.Element eElement) {
     NodeList nlList =  eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
     Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
     return nValue.getNodeValue();
```

And the output now is

```
name : Leo 
email : ******@*****.com
food :          
food : null
food :          
food : null
food :
```

Which quite confuses me. Could you tell me where I'm wrong? The number of food tags is not pre-defined.

Comment: Can you check `foodNode.getNodeType()` in your loop?

Comment: NodeList foodList = userEntryElement.getElementsByTagName("food-list").getChildNodes(); and Node foodNode = foodList.item(i); if(fooNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { Element userEntryElement = (Element) foodNode ; foodNode.getNodeValue()}

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If I check `foodNode.getNodeType == Node.Element_Node` before in the for loop before printing, I get two null output

Comment: @Nambari could you tell me why do you re-assign userEntryElement?

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey: I am sorry! I just copied your code (because I am hand typing). Use someother variable name, may be something like Element foodEntryElement instead.

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey try `((Node) foodNode.getChildNodes().item(0)).getNodeValue()`

Comment: @veer Boom!! It's working. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: If anyone can solve this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421506/how-to-parse-same-tag-name-in-android-xml-dom-parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((Node) foodNode.getChildNodes().item(0)).getNodeValue()
```

Note that, as you can clearly see, dealing with the DOM API in Java is pretty painful. Have you looked at [JDOM](http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-parsers/jdom) or [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

To get the sub elements of an element I've created a class that replace NodeList:

[ElementList as Replacement for NodeList](http://www.jroller.com/agoubard/entry/elementlist_as_replacement_for_nodelist)

Note that the code is public domain.

```
/*
 * The code of this file is in public domain.
 */
package org.xins.common.xml;

import Java.util.LinkedList;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import org.xins.common.text.ParseException;

/**
 * An ElementList is an NodeList with the following improvements:
*

    Implements List which make it iterable with for each loop *
    Only includes the direct child of the element *
    Only includes the elements *
    By default includes all direct child elements *
    Preserves the order of the child elements *
    Includes a method to get the sub element when unique * 


*
 * @author Anthony Goubard
*
 * @since XINS 3.0
 */
public class ElementList extends LinkedList {

   /**
    * The local name of the parent element.
    */
   private String parentName;

   /**
    * The local name of the child elements or * for all elements
    */
   private String childName;

   /**
    * Creates a list with all direct child element of the given element.
    *
    * @param element
    *    the parent element, cannot be null.
    */
   public ElementList(Element element) {
      this(element, "*");
   }

   /**
    * Creates a list with all direct child element with a specific local name of the given element.
    *
    * @param element
    *    the parent element, cannot be null.
    * @param childName
    *    the local name of the direct child elements that should be added to the list, cannot be null.
    */
   public ElementList(Element element, String childName) {
      parentName = element.getTagName();
      this.childName = childName;
      Node child = element.getFirstChild();
      while (child != null) {
         String newChildName = child.getLocalName();
         if (newChildName == null) {
            newChildName = child.getNodeName();
         }
         if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&
                 (childName.endsWith("*") || childName.equals(newChildName))) {
            add((Element) child);
         }
         child = child.getNextSibling();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Gets the unique child of this list.
    *
    * @return
    *    the sub-element of this element list, never null.
    *
    * @throws ParseException
    *    if no child with the specified name was found,
    *    or if more than one child with the specified name was found.
    */
   public Element getUniqueChildElement() throws ParseException {
      if (isEmpty()) {
         throw new ParseException("No \"" + childName + "\" child found in the \"" + parentName + "\" element.");
      } else if (size() > 1) {
         throw new ParseException("More than one \"" + childName + "\" children found in the \"" + parentName + "\" element.");
      }
      return get(0);
   }

   /**
    * Gets the first child of this element.
    *
    * @return
    *    the sub-element of this element, or null if no element is found.
    */
   public Element getFirstChildElement() {
      if (isEmpty()) {
         return null;
      }
      return get(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [NodeList](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NodeList.html) class and implements [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

```
public class NodeList<T extends Node> extends JavaScriptObject implements Iterable<T> {

  protected NodeList() {
  }

  public final native T getItem(int index) /*-{
    return this[index];
  }-*/;

  public final native int getLength() /*-{
    return this.length;
  }-*/;

  @Override
  final public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new NodeIterator<T>(this);
  }
}

public class NodeIterator<T extends Node> implements Iterator<T> {
  private int cursor = 0;
  private NodeList<T> nodeList;

  public NodeIterator(NodeList<T> nodeList) {
    this.nodeList = nodeList;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor < nodeList.getLength();
  }

  @Override
  public T next() {
    if (hasNext()) {
      return nodeList.getItem(cursor++);
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
  }

  @Override
  public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** NodeIterator needs to be in separate file.